# Start ipython cluster using ssh on windows machine

Tags: ssh, ipython

I have a problem setting up a ipython cluster on a Windows server and connecting to this ipcluster using a ssh connection. I tried following the tutorial on https://ipython.org/ipython/doc/dev/parallel/parallel_process.html#ssh, but I have problems to understand what the options mean exactly and what parameters are to use exactly...

Could anyone help a total noob to set up an ipcluster? (Let's say the remote machine has ip `192.168.0.1` and the local machine has `192.168.0.2`)

Answer (score 0):

If you scroll roughly to the middle of the page https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/parallel/parallel_process.html#ssh you will find this:

> Current limitations of the SSH mode of ipcluster are:
>
> - Untested and unsupported on Windows. Would require a working ssh on Windows. Also, we are using shell scripts to setup and execute
>     commands on remote hosts.

That means, there is no easy way to build an ipcluster with ssh connection on windows (if it works at all).

Comment: Argh, didn't see that :( Is it probably possible using ipcontroller and ipengine seperately? (controller local, engine remotely)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to connect the machines with an ssh connection? I guess it's possible with a ssh client on each windows machine, but if you are in a *trusted* local network you can also decide not to use the loopback interface and just expose the ports...
Sure you can start controller and engine separately! For further examples about ports (if you have problems with firewalls) see also [How to setup ssh tunnel for ipython cluster (ipcluster)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145650/how-to-setup-ssh-tunnel-for-ipython-cluster-ipcluster/31479269)