# ipyparallel/ipcluster inside docker container

Tags: docker, ipython

I am running an ipcluster on a linux host. The setup is very similar to this SO question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/31479269/2146052).

I have the following adjustments to my `ipcontroller_config.py`

```
myip = '*'
c.HubFactory.engine_ip = myip
c.HubFactory.client_ip = myip
c.HubFactory.monitor_ip = myip
c.HubFactory.ip = myip

c.HubFactory.iopub = (10001, 10002)
c.HubFactory.control = (10003,10004)
c.HubFactory.task = (10005,10006)
c.HubFactory.mux = (10007,10008)
c.HubFactory.regport = 10009
c.HubFactory.hb = (10010,10011)
c.HubFactory.notifier_port = 10012
```

I start the docker container as

```
docker run -it --rm -p 10000-10012:10000-10012 <myimg> /bin/bash
ipcluster start -n4
```

The ipcluster starts ok but when I try to connect I get `Hub connection timeout`. This error does not occur if I run the same configuration outside of docker. Do I need to make a further adjustment beyond the simple port forwarding?

Comment: Any luck with this? Seeing the same thing

Comment: No luck so far, unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally here is the missing piece:

When connecting from a different docker container one needs to specify `location` inside the configuration:

```
c.IPControllerApp.location = '<name of service in docker-compose>'
```

This is documented under  https://ipyparallel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/process.html#ports-and-addresses (see --location section for more information)

Also make sure that the two services are on the same docker network
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38089080/2146052 and see
https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

`ipcontroller_config.py` should therefore look like this (if running parallel for the first time one needs to create the default config by running: `ipython profile create --parallel --profile=myprofile`)

```
myip = '*'
c.HubFactory.engine_ip = myip
c.HubFactory.client_ip = myip
c.HubFactory.monitor_ip = myip
c.HubFactory.ip = myip
# c.IPControllerApp.location = '<name of service in docker-compose>'
c.IPControllerApp.location = 'ipyp'

c.HubFactory.iopub = (10001, 10002)
c.HubFactory.control = (10003,10004)
c.HubFactory.task = (10005,10006)
c.HubFactory.mux = (10007,10008)
c.HubFactory.regport = 10009
c.HubFactory.hb = (10010,10011)
c.HubFactory.notifier_port = 10012
```

Sample `docker-compose.yml` setup

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  ipyp:
    image: "ipyp"
    build: .
    ports:
     - "10000-10012:10000-10012"
    command: ipcluster start -n2 --profile=myprofile
    volumes:
      - configdata:/root/.ipython/
    restart: always

  ipyp_test:
    image: "ipyp"
    build: .
    ports:
     - "9999:9999"
    command: jupyter lab --allow-root --port 9999 --ip=0.0.0.0
    volumes:
      -configdata:/parallelconfig:ro
    restart: always

volumes:
  configdata:
```

Try out the setup by starting a notebook inside the ipyp_test service and running

```
import ipyparallel
fl = '/parallelconfig/profile_myprofile/security/ipcontroller-client.json'
rc = ipyparallel.Client(fl)
rc.ids
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an updated set of parameters in ipcontroller_config.py for ipyparallel 8.4.1
I suggest an update so the settings will work for ipyparallel 8.4.1

```
c.IPController.ports = [10000,10001,10002,10003,10004]
c.IPController.client_ports = [10005,10006,10007,10008]
c.IPController.engine_ports = [10009,10010,10011,10012]
c.IPController.location = 'ipyp'
```

instead of the the following deprecated settings

```
c.IPController.iopub = (10001,10002)
c.IPController.control = (10003,10004)
c.IPController.task = (10005,10006)
c.IPController.mux = (10007,10008)
c.IPController.regport = 10009
c.IPController.hb = (10010,10011)
c.IPController.notifier_port = 10012
```